# What kind of maths is needed to evaluate the Ramanujan Tau function?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I'm currently working through a book on number theory wherein Ramanujan's Tau function is defined by

$x\prod_{1=n}^{\infty}(1-x^n)^{24} = \sum_{1=n}^{\infty}\tau(n)x^n$

and the very first part of the question is evaluating $\tau(n)$ for $n\leq6$.

I haven't yet started a university maths course, which means that there are some fairly large gaps in my knowledge - I know a large amount of Abstract Algebra, and the standard first year of a UK analysis course, but no linear algebra at present, for example.

The book I'm reading "A course in number theory", by H.E. Rose, is stated as having most of the prerequisites covered in the first year of a UK maths course, but right now I cannot see any way to evaluate a function defined in such a way. What kind of maths is required to evaluate such a function? Is it likely that I haven't studied it yet?

I'm not too sure about the tags.

Comment: Hint: start by computing $(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)(1-x^5)$ keeping after every product only the powers of $x$ $\le 5$. You'll get $1-x-x^2+x^5$. Evaluate the cube with the same restriction, square three times with the same restriction and ...

Comment: And that will give you $x\prod_{1=n}^5(1-x^n)^{24}...

Comment: Once multiplied by $x$ you'll obtain the six first coefficients at the right. You'll get $1-24x+252\,x^2+\cdots$ and deduce the first coefficients of $\tau(n)$.

Comment: So...does that then evaluate the sum up to $n=5$?

Comment: Well you won't get the sum but the smallest coefficients of the series at the right : $x-24x^2+252\,x^3+\cdots$ and thus deduce $\tau(1)=1, \tau(2)=-24,\cdots$ (the product by $x$ was missing in my previous comment).

Comment: The product at the left is a [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for the coefficients at the right. This free [book](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) may help to learn much more about G.F. (but not about $\tau$).

Comment: Oh of course! I should really try jumping into a problem before seeking help, I suppose I was a bit too intimidated by the format to try anything

Comment: Just a quick question...would it be considered cheating to use something such as wolfram to calculate the coefficients of $((1-x)\dots(1-x^5))^{24}$? I understand that I don't need to do that, but I'm just curious for when I do go to uni

Comment: Well I don't think that W.A. could be used in an exam (but who knows...) so yes it is cheating. But since number theory exists for a long time it is not even sure that the problem's author did think at using computers... (of course I used C.A. for the expansion ! :-) )

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Since you enjoy online resources you may appreciate the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000594)...